# Email sending multiple cc addresses

Tags: c#

I have to send mail with multiple cc addresses.
For now this code only works with one.
Here's the code:

```
MailAddress addressTo = new MailAddress("ma@.asd.a");
                            MailAddress addressFrom = new MailAddress("ma@.asd.a");
                            MailMessage MyMessage = new MailMessage("ma@.asd.a", "ma@.asd.a");

                            MyMessage.Subject = "New requests";
                            MyMessage.Body = @"Body";

                            MailAddress copy = new MailAddress("ma@.asd.a");
                            MyMessage.CC.Add(copy);

                            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
                            client.Port = 32;
                            client.EnableSsl = false;
                            client.Host = "my-smtp";
                            client.Timeout = 10000;
                            client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
                            client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential(LocalUserName, "");

                            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

                            client.Send(MyMessage);
```

I allready tyed this:

```
MailAddress copy2 = new MailAddress("maas@.asd.a");
                            MyMessage.CC.Add(copy2)
```

But it's not working the request has time out error.

Can someone help me with this ?

Comment: So it works if you do not add the additional **cc**? That is strange. Since it looks like proper code. I use this all the time. I only never use uppercase for my variables. So I'd use `myMessage` instead of `MyMessage`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add them individually:

```
MyMessage.CC.Add("a@a.com");
```

Or add multiple as a AddRange:

```
MyMessage.CC.AddRange("a@a.com", "b@b.com");
```

Comment: I erased the copy part and just added multiple MyMessage.CC.Add emails and it works great! Thanks! :)